# Can autograd in pytorch handle a repeated use of a layer within the same module?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, autograd

I have a layer `layer` in an `nn.Module` and use it two or more times during a single `forward` step. The output of this `layer` is later inputted to the same `layer`. Can pytorch's `autograd` compute the grad of the weights of this layer correctly?

```
def forward(x):
    x = self.layer(x)
    x = self.layer(x)
    return x
```

Complete example:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,in_dim,out_dim):
        super(net,self).__init__()
        self.layer = nn.Linear(in_dim,out_dim,bias=False)

    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.layer(x)
        x = self.layer(x)
        return x

input_x = torch.tensor([10.])
label = torch.tensor([5.])
n = net(1,1)
loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()

out = n(input_x)
loss = loss_fn(out,label)
n.zero_grad()
loss.backward()

for param in n.parameters():
    w = param.item()
    g = param.grad

print('Input = %.4f; label = %.4f'%(input_x,label))
print('Weight = %.4f; output = %.4f'%(w,out))
print('Gradient w.r.t. the weight is %.4f'%(g))
print('And it should be %.4f'%(4*(w**2*input_x-label)*w*input_x))
```

Output:

```
Input = 10.0000; label = 5.0000
Weight = 0.9472; output = 8.9717
Gradient w.r.t. the weight is 150.4767
And it should be 150.4766
```

In this example, I have defined a module with only one linear layer (`in_dim=out_dim=1` and no bias). `w` is the weight of this layer; `input_x` is the input value; `label` is the desired value. Since the loss is chosen as MSE, the formula for the loss is

`((w^2)*input_x-label)^2`

Computing by hand, we have

`dw/dx = 2*((w^2)*input_x-label)*(2*w*input_x)`

The output of my example above shows that `autograd` gives the same result as computed by hand, giving me a reason to believe that it can work in this case. But in a real application, the layer may have inputs and outputs of higher dimensions, a nonlinear activation function after it, and the neural network could have multiple layers.

What I want to ask is: can I trust `autograd` to handle such situation, but a lot more complicated than that in my example? How does it work when a layer is called iteratively?

Comment: Autograd will handle this fine. This is a standard approach for recurrent networks and weight sharing networks. As the mathematics dictates, backprop will accumulate gradients twice for the weights of `layer` in this case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will work just fine. From the perspective of the autograd engine this isn't a cyclic application since the resulting computation graph will unwrap the repeated computation as a linear sequence. To illustrate this, for a single layer you might have:

```
x -----> layer --------+
           ^           |
           |  2 times  |
           +-----------+
```

From the autograd perspective this looks like:

```
x ---> layer ---> layer ---> layer
```

Here `layer` is the same layer copied 3 times over the graph. This means when computing the gradient for the layer's weights they will be accumulated from all the three stages. So when using `backward`:

```
x ---> layer ---> layer ---> layer ---> loss_func
                                            |
       lback <--- lback <--- lback <--------+
         |          |          |
         |          v          |
         +------> weights <----+
                   _grad
```

Here `lback` represents the local derivative of the `layer` forward transformation which uses the upstream gradient as an input. Each one adds to the layer's `weights_grad`.

Recurrent Neural Networks use this repeated application of layers (cells) at their basis. See for example this tutorial about [Classifying Names with a Character-Level RNN](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/char_rnn_classification_tutorial.html).

Comment: One thing to note is that the gradient contributions from earlier layers may be smaller than later layers.